# Mysql - modify result dataset

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a program (flex) that queries a database and gets back a dataset (value, timestamp).  In the program I then put each value in the set through an algorithm to get a new value resulting in all the values being transformed.  Instead of having to do this transformation of data in my program I would like mysql to do it and send the results back.  Essentially, I would like to do a SELECT statement that returns a modified dataset.

Comment: @asawilliams - can you give an outline of what you want to achieve?  Otherwise responses may be more general than you'd like.

Comment: If you're at all worried about performance, I would recommend keeping your transformation logic in your program instead of in sql.  It is almost certainly faster to do it in your programming language, and the database tends to be the bottleneck in most applications so it helps to keep the database as unloaded as possible.  Of course, if speed isn't an issue do whatever makes for more readable code...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the computation can only be done in a stored procedure or function, yes - as long as you are using MySQL 5.0+.  I recommend reading [this article on MySQL stored procedures & functions](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_3525581_1/MySQL-Stored-Procedures-Part-1.htm).